# Looks like android studio can't find classes from dependency

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle, preferences

I wanted to make settings fragment for my app so I added preference dependency to my build.gradle

```
def preference_version = "1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preference_version"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preference_version"
```

but when I want to use any class from this library in XML Layout like for example

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="notifications"
        app:title="Enable message notifications"/>

    <Preference
        app:key="feedback"
        app:title="Send feedback"
        app:summary="Report technical issues or suggest new features"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'm getting errors:

- Cannot resolve class PreferenceScreen
- Cannot resolve class SwitchPreferenceCompat
- Cannot resolve class Preference

I tried to build project after using /gradlew clean but nothing helped, I tried to use different versions of dependencies, different versions of gradle and use only dependency for java and only dependency for kotlin multiple times with different configurations but nothing helped. What is strange outside of XML files everything seems to work just fine and I can use classes from this library just fine, but I need to make layout with PreferenceScreen class and it's not recognising it.

Comment: Have you tried adding the ```androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen``` prefix to the xml objects?

Comment: Yes, same problem. It looks like its just don't recognise it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you put the xml file under the "xml" folder?

It must be placed under "xml" folder not under "layout" folder

[image: Like this]

You have to use a PreferenceActivity and call the file with:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
```

Official documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings

Comment: Sadly I wish it would be that easy, it's in right folder res->layout,
standard androidx classes like androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout works just fine in this file

Comment: @ArekKubiński yes but the PreferenceScreen must be in the res->xml not in the res->layout folder

Comment: Yup, it was that easy, sorry that I read your initial message wrong